# Python Removing Duplicates in a String Using in and not in

Tags: python, string, accumulator

I'm trying to use the in and not in operators as well as the Accumulator Pattern to remove all duplicate letters from a string and return a new string while maintaining order.

```
withDups = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog"

def removeDups(s):
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    sWithoutDups = ""
    for eachChar in withDups:
        if eachChar in alphabet:
            sWithoutDups = eachChar + sWithoutDups
        return sWithoutDups

print(removeDups(withDups))
```

My current code returns only the first letter of the string. I'm very new to python and coding in general, so please excuse if I'm overlooking something simple, my current code is not even the right direction, or if I'm posting something that shouldn't be.

Comment: it would be faster and more explicit to use `alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ... }` although it is much longer. You could do `ìmport string` and `alphabet = set(string.ascii_letters)`

Comment: Also by doing this: `sWithoutDups = eachChar + sWithoutDups` you are appending the character to the head of the string, so you are building it backwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
withDups = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog"
withoutDups = ""

for letter in withDups:
    if letter not in withoutDups:
        withoutDups += letter

print withoutDups
```

Have in mind that whitespaces are considered a character too.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but would you mind explaining what 'withoutDups += letter' does exactly?

Comment: withoutDups is initiated as a empty string, `withuodDups += letter` is just appending the letter to the end of the string, is a shorthand for `withoutDups = withoutDups + letter`

Answer (score 5):

You return inside the for loop, which means you will never go to a second iteration of the loop.  I suspect you want that moved out one level of indentation so it's at the same level as the for, not inside it

Answer (score 2):

You were quite near. You need to move your `return` outside the for loop, this is because the function will return once it encounters the return statement. Also you need to update alphabet on the go, that is mark that the alphabet has already been visited by using a sentinel

```
def removeDups(s):
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    sWithoutDups = ""
    for eachChar in withDups:
        if eachChar in alphabet:
            sWithoutDups =  sWithoutDups + eachChar 
            alphabet = alphabet.replace(eachChar,'-')  # The character has 
                                                       # already been found
    return sWithoutDups        # Move return here
```

Output

```
TheQuickBrownFxJmpdOvLazyDg
```

A better way as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950441/python-removing-duplicates-in-a-string-using-in-and-not-in#comment48022012_29950489) would be

```
if eachChar not in sWithoutDups:
    sWithoutDups =  sWithoutDups + eachChar
```

In this way you would not need to have the sentinel over the alphabet.

Another way to do this is

```
def removeDups(s):    
    l = list(s)
    tmp = []
    for i in l:
        if i not in tmp and i != ' ':        
            tmp.append(i)
    tmp.remove(' ')
    return ''.join(tmp)
```

Comment: I would test `eachChar not in sWithoutDups` rather than `eachChar in alphabet` and updating `alphabet`.

Comment: you shouldn't misuse the list comprehension in your last example.

Comment: Thanks again. I have made the necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

Let Python do the work:

```
''.join(set(withDups))
```